# append json object to existing array of json object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to append new json object in existing json array of object. I am new in json. so please help me.

existing json :

```
{
   "cluster":[
      {
         "path":"home/Nik",
         "password":"welcome",
         "isQueen":"true",
         "host":"192.168.11.248",
         "isQueenWorker":"true",
         "user":"Nik"
      }
   ]
}
```

new json :

```
{
   "path":"home\/Nik",
   "password":"welcome",
   "isQueen":"true",
   "host":"192.168.11.248",
   "isQueenWorker":"true",
   "user":"Nik"
}
```

I want to add new json to existing json array.

Comment: Do you use GSON by Google? Is quite helpful https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Please add more information. This question is way too broad in its current state

Comment: please add more information, how do you expect json object look after appending new json?

Answer (score 1):

You may use it like below, you need to use push command to push an object inside an array.

```
var myObj = {
   "cluster":[
      {
         "path":"home/Nik",
         "password":"welcome",
         "isQueen":"true",
         "host":"192.168.11.248",
         "isQueenWorker":"true",
         "user":"Nik"
      }
   ]
};
var x = {
   "path":"home\/Nik",
   "password":"welcome",
   "isQueen":"true",
   "host":"192.168.11.248",
   "isQueenWorker":"true",
   "user":"Nik"
};
alert(JSON.stringify(myObj))
var newArr = myObj.cluster; 
newArr.push(x) //pushing object x in newArr. similarly you can add multiple objects in to it
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(newArr);
alert(myJSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly append it

eg.  first json

```
{"cluster":[{"path":"home/Nik","password":"welcome","isQueen":"true","host":"192.168.11.248","isQueenWorker":"true","user":"Nik"}]}
```

int i= cluster.length();

```
cluster[i]={"path":"home/Nik","password":"welcome","isQueen":"true","host":"192.168.11.248","isQueenWorker":"true","user":"Nik"}
```

Comment: sorry a small change i= cluster.length; this definitely works ,it worked for me